# Powershell securely logging in with user credentials

Tags: powershell, security, authentication

Is there a way in Powershell to securely log in to a server where the authentication process is "protected". I am fully aware of the use of credentials and secure strings to encrypt a password. My concern is what if someone gets gains access to the computer where the script resides and alters its intended usage but maintains the authentication information. Would they be able to then authenticate to AD and run their own script? Is there a way to prevent this with Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you save your password like this:

```
read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\cred.txt
```

It can only be used by **you** on that machine. So any other person that lays his hand on that file can not use it

**Edit**
Tested it. Tried to open such a file logged in as someone else:

```
PS> $pass = Get-Content .\credgj.txt|ConvertTo-SecureString
ConvertTo-SecureString : Key not valid for use in specified state.
At line:1 char:34
+ $pass = Get-Content .\credgj.txt|ConvertTo-SecureString
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], CryptographicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument_CryptographicError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
```

Comment: Ok, that helps a little. But if someone were to gain access to my account or a service account running the script could they then modify the script for their own usage?

Comment: Yes, if your account gets in somebody else's control, he/she can do the same things as you. If you want to protect your script against altering/tampering then signing might be a solution for you.